# How do I set all nonzero values in my matrix to 1 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a `matrix A`, the size of which is `40*20*20 double`. The minimum value of `matrix A` is `0`. The maximum value of `matrix A` is `126`. I want to set all nonzero values in `matrix A` to be `"1"`.I use this following command, but it does not work.

```
find(A(:,:,:)~= 0) = 1;
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: **Pleaaaase** change your question title. And remove `matlab-guide` from the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it with `logical` indexing.  Don't use `find`:

```
A(A ~= 0) = 1;
```

However, if it is your desire to replace all values in the matrix with either 0 or 1, where 1 is anything non-zero, you can simply create a `logical` matrix like so:

```
A = A ~= 0;
```

If it is your desire to also have this be a `double` matrix, you can easily do that by the [`uplus`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uplus.html) (unary plus) operator or cast to `double`<sup>1</sup>:

```
A = +(A ~= 0);
%// or
%A = double(A);
```

---

<sup>1. Credit goes to [Rafael Monteiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2325919/rafael-monteiro) for originally proposing the casting idea.  See his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32803092/3250829. I also decided to use the `uplus` operator to be different.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If zeros will remain as zeros, and everything else will turn to one, there is
no need for indexing nor find. You could do it like this:

```
A = A ~= 0;
```

However, it will create a logical matrix. If it **has** to be double, just cast it to double, like this:

```
A = double(A ~= 0);
```

Comment: I was also going to put that as an edit, but seeing as how you've already stated that, I won't :) +1.

Comment: Bah, I did it anyway.  I have acknowledged you as the originator of that idea though.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states (http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), the find function just returns the indices of the elements that satisfy the condition you give as a function paramter to find(). Hence your attempt to assign 1 to the return parameter of find() can not work.

Instead of using the find function, I would advise you to loop through the array contents and check each element individually. In combination with the size function (http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) you can create a size independent function for altering your array. Just store the return values of size() and use them as loop indices.

Comment: In this particular case, the use of loops are not needed.  Logical indexing is more than sufficient and performance-wise, it's faster.

Comment: You are very right. I did not know about this way of indexing, hence +1 from my side as well. (Once I am allowed to...)

Comment: Have a vote from me :)  welcome to StackOverflow btw!

Comment: Thanks! After benefiting from StackOverflow throughout my studies, I thought I better start to give something in return.

Answer (score 0):

`find` returns the indices, so if you want to access the values, you have to do `A(find(A)) = 1;`. Note that `find` finds indices of nonzero values by default: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Comment: In this particular case, using `logical` indexing is better performance wise.  See here for an informative discussion: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/66992-logical-indexing-is-usually-faster-than-find